# Can i get currently used hibernate dialect in grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails

I use grails 2.3.11 in my application.

Can i get currently used datasource dialect in runtime?

I just need to check what DB type i use (oracle or H2).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can call the `getDialect()` method in the SessionFactory. Dependency-inject the bean in a service or wherever:

```
def sessionFactory
```

and then the current Dialect instance is available using

```
Dialect dialect = sessionFactory.dialect
```